# Implement validation message for default size validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-validator

I have DTO which I want to restrict for size:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class CreateUserDTO {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=1, max=20, message = "'Login' value '${validatedValue}' must be between {min} and {max} characters long.")
    private String login;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=1, max=45, message = "'Email' value '${validatedValue}' must be between {min} and {max} characters long.")
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=1, max=20, message = "'First name' value '${validatedValue}' must be between {min} and {max} characters long.")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=1, max=20, message = "'Last name' value '${validatedValue}' must be between {min} and {max} characters long.")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Rest controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody CreateUserDTO dto) {

        .....

        return ok().build();
    }
```

Any idea why I get this huge error message:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 404,
            "code": "1001",
            "title": "Not found",
            "detail": "Validation failed for argument [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.engine.rest.UsersController.create(org.engine.dto.CreateUserDTO): [Field error in object 'createUserDTO' on field 'login': rejected value [56dtttttttttt444444444465st]; codes [Size.createUserDTO.login,Size.login,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [createUserDTO.login,login]; arguments []; default message [login],20,1]; default message ['Login' value '56dtttttttttt444444444465st' must be between 1 and 20 characters long.]] ",
            "extra": {
                "detail": "Validation failed for argument [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.engine.rest.UsersController.create(org.engine.dto.CreateUserDTO): [Field error in object 'createUserDTO' on field 'login': rejected value [56dtttttttttt444444444465st]; codes [Size.createUserDTO.login,Size.login,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [createUserDTO.login,login]; arguments []; default message [login],20,1]; default message ['Login' value '56dtttttttttt444444444465st' must be between 1 and 20 characters long.]] "
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `"56dtttttttttt444444444465st".length(); $4 ==> 27`. If the value is not what you sent, try `{value}` instead of `${validatedValue}`.

Comment: Show please how do you handle this exception

Comment: I use this code to handle exceptions: https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/tree/master/src/main/java/org/engine/exception

Comment: @PeterPenzov As the input passed is more than 20 chars,it throws the Validation Exception. Then it is handled by serverExceptionHandler which is defined inside EngineExceptionHandler.java which serves this response.

Comment: @PeterPenzov what version of spring boot / spring framework are you using?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-parent with Spring cloud dependency management 2020.0.3

Comment: @PeterPenzov - Could you please provide the feedback  to answers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the following `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` which works fine for me.

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {


  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
      MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
      HttpHeaders headers,
      HttpStatus status,
      WebRequest request) {
    Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> errors = new HashMap<>();
    ex.getBindingResult()
        .getAllErrors()
        .forEach(
            error -> {
              String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
              String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
              Map<String, String> errorFields = new HashMap<>();
              errorFields.put("field", fieldName);
              errorFields.put("message", errorMessage);
              Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> errorMap = new HashMap<>();
              errorMap.put("errors", List.of(errorFields));
              errors.put(fieldName, errorMap);
            });

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(errors);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the linked repo in your comment you could just add a new exception handler to customize constraint related validation errors.

Right now all the undefined exceptions are routed to as defined [`here`](https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/exception/EngineExceptionHandler.java#L41).

You can define a exception handler for constraint related errors in the [`EngineExceptionhandler`](https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/exception/EngineExceptionHandler.java) class.

Something like

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDTO> constraintValidationException(final ConstraintViolationException e) {
    List<ErrorRerponse> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ConstraintViolation violation : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
        error.setTitle(violation.getPropertyPath().toString());
        error.setDetail(violation.getMessage());
        errors.add(error);
    }
    ErrorResponseDTO errorResponse = new ErrorResponseDTO();
    errorResponse.setErrors(errors);
    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseDTO>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

You can add more customization based on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Simply The error message says where the issue is

```
default message ['Login' value '56dtttttttttt444444444465st' must be between 1 and 20 characters long.]
```

Since the value, you passed to `login` in `CreateUserDTO dto` with the request having characters more than the max value you have defined(20). Since the validation is failed It throws this error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle `MethodArgumentNotValidException`

A quick implementation would be like

```
@ExceptionHandler({ MethodArgumentNotValidException.class })
public ResponseEntity<Void> handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    BindingResult bindingResult = ex.getBindingResult();
    for (FieldError fieldError : bindingResult.getFieldErrors()) {
        // Do something with fieldError.getDefaultMessage();
        // Which is equivalent to 'Login' value '${validatedValue}' must be between {min} and {max} characters long.
    }

    for (ObjectError objectError : bindingResult.getGlobalErrors()) {
        // Do something with objectError.getDefaultMessage();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the root exception and beautify it before showing to end user or sending to client. As in mentioned above answers, you can override `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` method from `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` as I did below:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ServiceExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
            sb.append("[");
            sb.append(((FieldError) error).getField());
            sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(error.getDefaultMessage());
            sb.append("] ");
        });

    log.error("Method arg is invalid. " + sb.toString(), ex);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(sb.toString(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

`log.error()` prints the message below:

```java
// here is the message I show to the end user
10:27:02 [ERROR] [ServiceExceptionHandler] 141: Method arg is invalid. [shareList size must be between '1' and '10'] 
// here is the stack trace you encountered
org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public
...
[Size.eyatTransferDTO.shareList,Size.shareList,Size.java.util.List,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [eyatTransferDTO.shareList,shareList]; arguments []; default message [shareList],10,1]; default message [size must be between '1' and '10']]
...
```